# Implementing NSFastEnumerator: EXC_BAD_ACCESS when iterating with for…in

Tags: objective-c, ios, enumeration

I have a data structure that I wanted to enumerate. I tried to implement my object's NSFastEnumerator as follows:

```
- (NSUInteger)countByEnumeratingWithState:(NSFastEnumerationState *)state 
                                  objects:(__unsafe_unretained id [])buffer 
                                    count:(NSUInteger)len {

    NSUInteger c = 0;
    while (c < len) {
        id obj = [self objectAtIndex:state->state];
        if (obj == nil) break;
        buffer[c] = obj;
        c++;
        state->state++;
    }
    state->itemsPtr = buffer;
    state->mutationsPtr = nil;
    return c;
}
```

If I use objectAtIndex directly, my object works properly. I get a nil when the index doesn't exist. But when I then use the for loop:

```
for (Pin *pin in coll) { ... }
```

the code runs through the above function fine and fills in state with what appears to be valid values and returns the number of objects, then I get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS failure at the for statement itself.

What am I doing wrong in this implementation?

Answer (score 2):

I just had a similar issues, and after looking more closely into Apple's [FastEnumerationSample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/FastEnumerationSample/Listings/FastEnumerationSample_mm.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009411-FastEnumerationSample_mm-DontLinkElementID_3), this part (that I had overlooked) jumped at me:

```
// We are not tracking mutations, so we'll set state->mutationsPtr to point into one of our extra values,
// since these values are not otherwise used by the protocol.
// If your class was mutable, you may choose to use an internal variable that is updated when the class is mutated.
// state->mutationsPtr MUST NOT be NULL.
state->mutationsPtr = &state->extra[0];
```

The important part being: `state->mutationsPtr` *MUST NOT be NULL*. I just used the example line provided and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using ARC. The problem may be that the `buffer` is an array of `__unsafe_unretained` objects, so ARC might be over-releasing them. But what does your `objectAtIndex:` method look like? This shouldn't be a problem if you are returning objects that are guaranteed to be alive at least as long as your object itself.

Comment: My objectAtIndex: method is supported by an NSMutableArray underneath, and all the memory management is handled by the array. The method signature is generated by XCode itself so I'm assuming its correct, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: Yes, I think it's correct, I see it in my header files. If you're using an NSMutableArray I can't imagine why this would be a problem. I would recommend asking on http://devforums.apple.com.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
id obj = [self objectAtIndex:state->state];
```

use

```
__unsafe_unretained id  = [self objectAtIndex:state->state];
```